# How to build a directive to disable all type of material controls?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to build an angular directive which when applied on any control(material controls) like matButton/matSelect/matAutcomplete etc.., should disable  control based on a condition. Any help.?

Comment: is the condition common for all these controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the process:

Create your directive using the angular cli

`ng generate directive customMatDisable`

This will create a new directive file for you `.directive.ts`

Inside the directive file manipulate the element like so

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[customMatDisable]'
})
export class CustomMatDisableDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       if(//condition here){
          el.nativeElement.disabled = true;
       }
    }
}
```

and use it like below:
`<button customMatDisable mat-raised-button >Button Text</button>`

**Update**

Since it seems that the material directives override our disabled status since its initialization takes place after our directive executes. One workaround would be to do it like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[customMatDisable]'
})
export class CustomMatDisableDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       if(//condition here){
          setTimeout(()=>{
            el.nativeElement.disabled = true;
            el.nativeElement.classList.add("mat-button-disabled")
          },1) //execute after 1 ms
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey...thanks for your time.. but... i have tried this... this actually don't work for matbuttons... i have created a stackblitz.. you can check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zirk9y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.ts

Comment: @krishna Seems like our directive executed before the material ones and their initialization overrode our disabled status. A work around is to wrap our statement in a setTimeout. I shall update the answer accordingly.

Comment: this would disable the action but the styles are not updated.... i have updated the stackblitz... is there any we could do that?

Comment: @AdityaMenon, NOT put 1 to execute after 1ms. When Angular find a setTimeout, it repaint the application after. btw better put in ngOnInit

Comment: @krishna yes, we just need to add a class for that, updating again. Showing an example for a button. In your actual code use a switch case to determine which type of element it is and add the corresponding class

Comment: Input control and by extension Autocomplete wont require an additional class, select and button will. The rest youll need to determine based on what youre using

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach is inject in constructor buttons,matInput.. and disable it

```
export class CustomMatDisableDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    @Optional() @Self() private control:NgControl,
    @Optional() @Self() private button:MatButton,
    @Optional() @Self() private input:MatInput,
    @Optional() @Self() private select:MatSelect,
    @Optional() @Self() private toogle:MatDatepickerToggle<any>,
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.control && this.control.control)
      this.control.control.disable()

    if (this.button)
      this.button.disabled=true
    if (this.input)
      this.input.disabled=true;
    if (this.select)
      this.select.disabled=true;
    if (this.toogle)
      this.toogle.disabled=true;
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zirk9y-vndsum?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdisable.directive.ts)

Comment: this working like a star but if I have ngmodel in my html element its not working